# Remove invariant column in R

Tags: r

I want to remove a column if it is invariant for `[2:nrow(df), ]`

Just cant get this to work.  Still new to R and programming in general.

```
red    <- c(1, 2, 3)
blue   <- c(4, 5, 4)
green  <- c(4, 7, 2)
colors <- data.frame(red, blue, green)
colors <- t(colors)
colors

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
red      1    2    3
blue     4    5    4
green    4    7    2
```

How to remove column 1 logically due to invariance of blue and green.  It doesn't specifically need to be variance any method to remove columns that have all the same values will do the job.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to remove a column, just reassign the object less the column:

```
colors <- colors[, -1]
colors

#       [,1] [,2]
# red      2    3
# blue     5    4
# green    7    2
```

If you have a list of columns to drop (technically a `vector`, not an R `list`), use:

```
toDrop <- c( <whichever columns to drop> )
colors <- colors[, -toDrop]
```

Alternatively, if you know which you are keeping:

```
toKeep <- c( <whichever columns to keep> )
colors <- colors[, toKeep]
```

---

As for determining if it is invariant, use `duplicated`, but not on the data.frame directly but rather on each column (using the function `apply`):

```
toDrop <- apply(colors[2:nrow(colors), ], 2, function(x) all(duplicated(x)[-1] ))

# Optionally:
toDrop <- which(toDrop)
if (length(toDrop))
   colors <- colors[, -toDrop]
```

Comment: I doubt the header name is causing the code to fail. Unless you're doing something other than described

Comment: Your code returns TRUE FALSE FALSE and gives the expected result with [,-todrop].  Mine gives example, toDrop[2] = HEADER <nextline> FALSE.  When I do df[,-toDrop] it returns a dataframe with 0 columns.  So it doesn't fail, but it fails to work as intended.

Comment: You're right.  Its not the headers that is causing it to fail, but something is.